# Issue connecting to PHP with Ajax chat

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Using Ajax integrated chat with PHPBB3. It is supposed to use the mysql connections that the site uses. The database tables have been created. When accessing, I continue to get the error

`'>[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/phpbb/di/container_builder.php on line 291:` `file_put_contents([ROOT]/chat/../cache/container_[ROOT]/chatslashdotdotslash.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument Error-Report: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Error-Code: 2002'`

Edit: I have not had any trouble connecting to the database with the web application itself. I've read that the hosts file may need to be edited. I made sure that the socket server option for AJAX chat is set to false. I'm not sure what this error is actually trying to say here or what the actual connection error is. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The php class container_builder is where the error falls. Here is the function being called at that point:

```
protected function dump_container($container_filename)
{
    $dumper = new PhpDumper($this->container);
    $cached_container_dump = $dumper->dump(array(
        'class'         => 'phpbb_cache_container',
        'base_class'    => 'Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder',
    ));
    file_put_contents($container_filename, $cached_container_dump);
```

I cleared out the particular cache file, which was then recreated, but the error does not go away. I would think there is no problem with connectivity to the database by the application.  Cache is stored on the server not the database.

Comment: Sounds like your database is firewalled.

Comment: It means that the connection is being refused. Why? I don't know. But can you explain exactly what you are trying to do, with a short code that demonstrates the problem?